# print a page using xslt

Tags: xslt

How can print a page using xslt.
i need a link, or a button which when clicked invokes the print page printer dialog box.

Comment: you want XSLT to add a link which invokes the printer dialog? Please try to explain a bit more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to specify a bit more about what you are trying to do.

XSLT is simply a way to turn one block of text into another.  The input is generally an xml buffer and the output is some text rendering of that buffer.

It is possible that you are trying to generate a script using XSLT and that you want that script to be able to open a print dialog when it is run by something e.g. you generate javascript, that then runs on a browser.

Can you describe in more detail what you want to achieve?

The following in an html page gives you a print link:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is a language for transforming XML documents. That means you can add/modify content. Assuming your output is HTML, you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="top">
  <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
          <input name="print" type="button" value="Print" 
                 onclick="javascript:window.print()">
          <xsl:apply-templates />
     </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

But of course, where exactly the button has to go depends on your needs. I'd additionally, add a media=print specific CSS at the top so that the document comes out neat!